# How to extract data of WAV file into an array using J2ME - JavaME

Tags: java, java-me, wav

If I have a WAV file and it its data (include header) like this:

52 49 46 46 24 08 00 00 57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20 10 00 00 00 01 00 02 00 
22 56 00 00 88 58 01 00 04 00 10 00 64 61 74 61 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 
24 17 1e f3 3c 13 3c 14 16 f9 18 f9 34 e7 23 a6 3c f2 24 f2 11 ce 1a 0d ...

How can I get it into an array in J2ME ?

Answer (score 1):

The `FileInputStream` class has a `readByte()` method that you can use to read the raw content of a data file, a couple of byte at a time.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[])